# how can I check from firestore how many items have a true or false value and show only the true in a list? - flutter

Tags: list, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, boolean

I want to make that in a Todo app, only the elements that have the true value are showing in the list. How can I do this?

Comment: add some code to get better help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check using where in your stream like this

```
Stream<List<TodoItem>> getSomeoneItems() {
 return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('items')
   .where('your field name', isEqualTo: true)
   .snapshots()
   .map((qSnap) =>
     qSnap.docs.map((doc) => TodoItem.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we consider this is your list

```
List = [
   Model(name:"1" , val: true)
   Model(name:"2" , val: false)
   Model(name:"3" , val: true)

]
```

and with the below code we can find items with true val

```
List result = [];
a.forEach((element) {
  if(element.val == true){
    result.add(element);
  }
})
```